# How to set a Header to a QListView

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qlistview, qheaderview

I am having a **QListView** which has 5 items in it. say(*America, Canada, Denmark, Egypt, Finland*) in my QListView. Now i want to set a common **Header for all this items as COUNTRIES**.  How can i set a Header to a QListView. Please Help.

Comment: The QListView documentation says : *This view does not display horizontal or vertical headers; to display a list of items with a horizontal header, use QTreeView instead.*

Comment: Firstly, if you are using QListView, you'll be using a model. If you are using a model, subclass it just overload the member function `headerData ( int, Qt::Orientation, const QVariant &, int )` to give the header.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can not directly but, you can do this.

```
    mHb = new QHBoxLayout;
    {

        QVBoxLayout *tInnerVB = new QVBoxLayout;
        {
            QLabel *tHeader = new QLabel("Team List");
            tHeader->setFont(QFont("FontAwesome"));
            tInnerVB->addWidget(tHeader);

            mTeamViewModel->setStringList(BDatabase::instance()->getTeamList());
            mLeTeamList->setModel(mTeamViewModel);
            tInnerVB->addWidget(mLeTeamList);

        }
        mHb->addLayout(tInnerVB);

        tInnerVB = new QVBoxLayout;
        {
            QLabel *tHeader = new QLabel("Team Members");
            tHeader->setFont(QFont("FontAwesome"));
            tInnerVB->addWidget(tHeader);

            mMembersViewModel->setStringList(QStringList());
            mLeTeamMembers->setModel(mMembersViewModel);
            tInnerVB->addWidget(mLeTeamMembers);

        }
        mHb->addLayout(tInnerVB);


    }
```

The output would be like:

[image]

Moreover, you can change orientation, alignment and other things by the label. Good coding :)